# My Winform application UI hang after taking remote control

Tags: vb.net

My Winform application run on machine A. I took remote control of machine A from machine B then disconnect network connection in machine B. After sometime reconnect network connection I saw my application execute my script but application UI is in hung state.

So I used WinDbg(x64) for debug i saw application main thread is stuck with this log

```
    ntdll.dll!ZwWaitForMultipleObjects+0x14
KERNELBASE.dll!WaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0xf0
USER32.dll!MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx+0x1e0
combase.dll!Ordinal111+0x63b
combase.dll!CoGetCurrentLogicalThreadId+0x20f
combase.dll!CoWaitForMultipleHandles+0xb3
clr.dll!MetaDataGetDispenser+0xcd4a
clr.dll!MetaDataGetDispenser+0xccb4
clr.dll!MetaDataGetDispenser+0x76efd
clr.dll!MetaDataGetDispenser+0x8f4d5
[Managed to Unmanaged Transition]
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne+0x1b
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne+0x2e
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.WaitForWaitHandle+0x1ed
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke+0x431
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke+0x60
System.Windows.Forms.dll!System.Windows.Forms.WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext.Send+0x74
System.dll!SystemEventInvokeInfo.Invoke+0x9c
System.dll!Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.RaiseEvent+0x129
System.dll!Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.OnDisplaySettingsChanging+0x76
System.dll!Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.WindowProc+0x272
[Unmanaged to Managed Transition]
[Native Frame: IL Method without Metadata]
clr.dll+0x21fe
USER32.dll!CallWindowProcW+0x4d0
USER32.dll!DispatchMessageW+0x1af
[Native Frame: IL Method without Metadata]
[Managed to Unmanaged Transition]
System.Windows.Forms.dll!ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop+0x33e
System.Windows.Forms.dll!ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner+0x1c6
System.Windows.Forms.dll!ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop+0x51
Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll!Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.OnRun+0xa5
Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll!Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.DoApplicationModel+0x95
Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll!Microsoft.VisualBasic.ApplicationServices.WindowsFormsApplicationBase.Run+0x3ca
ExecutionAgent.exe!Execution.Agent.My.MyApplication.Main+0x64
[Unmanaged to Managed Transition]
clr.dll!LogHelp_LogAssert+0x1bf3
clr.dll!LogHelp_LogAssert+0x1ac5
clr.dll!LogHelp_LogAssert+0x27cd
clr.dll!SetRuntimeInfo+0x1580
clr.dll!SetRuntimeInfo+0x1dca
clr.dll!SetRuntimeInfo+0x1c87
clr.dll!SetRuntimeInfo+0x161d
clr.dll!SetRuntimeInfo+0x1402
clr.dll!CorExeMain+0x14
mscoreei.dll!CorExeMain+0x6d
MSCOREE.DLL!CorExeMain+0x6c
KERNEL32.dll!BaseThreadInitThunk+0x14

ntdll.dll!RtlUserThreadStart+0x21
```

Any ideas on what is causing this problem.

Thanks

Comment: If you were loged out on macine A when disconnecting, this could be the issue

Comment: It is a very traditional deadlock, caused by creating a Form object on more than one thread.  The SystemEvents class is always around to make that a pretty fatal mistake.  Judging from the stack trace, in this scenario it is convinced that another thread is the UI thread.  A custom splash screen that uses controls, like a ProgressBar, is a common cause.